# login api call failed , password is showing uninitialised afterwards

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

After registration process , I tried to login but its showing that password is not initialised ,
when i am trying to print the password initially it is gettign printed , but after the querying part , it is showing not initialised , why is this happening

here is the code

```
export const login = async (req,res)=>{
    const { email,password} = req.body;

    console.log(email,password);
    if(!email || !password ){
        return res.status(502).json({
            error:"all fields are required",
            message:"try again"
        })
    }

    console.log(password);
    
    const q = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email = ?";
    db.query(q,[email,password],(err,data)=>{
        if(err){
            return res.status(501).json({
                success:false,
                message:err.message,
                data:"query problem"
            })
        }
        if(!data){
            return res.status(502).json({
                success:false,
                message:"no user exists"
            })
        }
        console.log('password is ',password);
        if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password,data[0].password)){
            return res.status(503).json({
                success:false,
                message:"password doesnot match"
            })
        }
        const {password,...other} = data[0];
        const token = jwt.sign({id:data[0].id},"jwtkey");
        res.cookie('access_token',token,{
            httpOnly:true
        }).status(200).json({
            message:other
        })
    })

}
```

here is what i am getting in my terminal

> [nodemon] starting `node index.js` database connection established
> successfully and listening to port abc@xyz@gmail.com 12345 12345
> file:///C:/Users/lenovo/OneDrive/Desktop/blogSite/server/controllers/auth.js:98
> console.log('password is ',password);
> ^
>
> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'password' before initialization
> at Query.onResult (file:///C:/Users/lenovo/OneDrive/Desktop/blogSite/server/controllers/auth.js:98:3

I am expecting that password should be printed later also , is there some scoping mistakes here , please elaborate

Comment: see: _Disallow variable declarations from shadowing variables declared in the outer scope_ [no-shadow](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-shadow)

Comment: It should be a problem with your variable scope. You have initialized the   ```const {password,...other} = data[0];```. But before initialising the variable you are trying to access the variable in the ``` console.log('password is ', password)```. Use the variable names properly will resolve the issue

Answer (score -1):

You're passing both `email` and `password` as parameters to your SQL query, but your query only requires `email`.
You can modify the query by this

```
const q = "SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
db.query(q, [email, password], (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({
            success: false,
            message: err.message,
            data: "query problem"
        });
    }
```

Comment: This would mean the password is saved as plaintext - which it's not. See the original code: `bcrypt.compareSync(password,data[0].password)`

Comment: FYI: Your snippet is also syntactically incorrect...